# How to make the sound sliders disappear in pause menu?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have been trouble on how to get rid of the sliders on pause menu. I was wondering if there a piece of code or any ideas that if you click resume you will terminate the sliders that control the music

./m file

```
   -(void)PauseButtonTapped:(id)sender
 {
   if(_pauseScreenUp ==FALSE)
   {
    _pauseScreenUp=TRUE;
    //if you have music uncomment the line bellow
    //[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] pauseBackgroundMusic];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    CGSize s = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    pauseLayer = [CCColorLayer layerWithColor: ccc4(150, 150, 150, 125) width: s.width height: s.height];
    pauseLayer.position = CGPointZero;
    [self addChild: pauseLayer z:8];

    _pauseScreen =[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pause picture.png"] retain];
    _pauseScreen.position= ccp(250,150);
    [self addChild:_pauseScreen z:8];

    CCMenuItem *ResumeMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage
                                  itemFromNormalImage:@"resume.png" selectedImage:@"resume.png"
                                  target:self selector:@selector(ResumeButtonTapped:)];
    ResumeMenuItem.position = ccp(250, 230);

    CCMenuItem *QuitMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage
                                itemFromNormalImage:@"quit.png" selectedImage:@"quit.png"
                                target:self selector:@selector(QuitButtonTapped:)];
    QuitMenuItem.position = ccp(250, 50);




    CCMenuItem *MainMenuItem = [CCMenuItemImage
                                itemFromNormalImage:@"mainmenubutton.png" selectedImage:@"mainmenubutton.png"
                                target:self selector:@selector(MainButtonTapped:)];
    MainMenuItem.position = ccp(250, 145);         






    CCControlSlider *slider = [CCControlSlider sliderWithBackgroundFile:@"sound bar.png" progressFile:@"sound bar.png" thumbFile:@"sound icon.png"];





    slider.minimumValue = 0.0f; // Sets the min value of range
    slider.maximumValue = 1.0f; // Sets the max value of range

    // When the value of the slider will change, the given selector will be call
    [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged:) forControlEvents:CCControlEventValueChanged];

    [slider setPosition:ccp(240,68)];        





    [self addChild:slider z:8];         






    CCControlSlider *slider1 = [CCControlSlider sliderWithBackgroundFile:@"sound bar2.png" progressFile:@"sound bar2.png" thumbFile:@"devil2.png"];





    slider1.minimumValue = 0.0f; // Sets the min value of range
    slider1.maximumValue = 1.0f; // Sets the max value of range

    // When the value of the slider will change, the given selector will be call
    [slider1 addTarget:self action:@selector(valueChanged1:) forControlEvents:CCControlEventValueChanged];

    [slider1 setPosition:ccp(240,8)];        





    [self addChild:slider1 z:10];         














    _pauseScreenMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:ResumeMenuItem,QuitMenuItem,MainMenuItem, nil];
    _pauseScreenMenu.position = ccp(0,0);
    [self addChild:_pauseScreenMenu z:10];








}
 }








 -(void)ResumeButtonTapped:(id)sender{
[self removeChild:_pauseScreen cleanup:YES];
[self removeChild:_pauseScreenMenu cleanup:YES];
[self removeChild:pauseLayer cleanup:YES];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
_pauseScreenUp=FALSE;
 }

 -(void)QuitButtonTapped:(id)sender{
[self removeChild:_pauseScreen cleanup:YES];
[self removeChild:_pauseScreenMenu cleanup:YES];
[self removeChild:pauseLayer cleanup:YES];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
_pauseScreenUp=FALSE;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] performSelector:@selector(terminateWithSuccess)];

  }





 -(void)MainButtonTapped:(id)sender{
[self removeChild:_pauseScreen cleanup:YES];
[self removeChild:_pauseScreenMenu cleanup:YES];
[self removeChild:pauseLayer cleanup:YES];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
_pauseScreenUp=FALSE;
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[MainMenuScene scene]];    
   }









  - (void)soundOnOrOff:(id)sender
{

if ([[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] mute]) {
    // This will unmute the sound
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setMute:0];
}
else {
    //This will mute the sound
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setMute:1];
}

 }


- (void)valueChanged:(CCControlSlider *)sender
{
// Change volume of your sounds

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setBackgroundMusicVolume:sender.value];
 }



  - (void)valueChanged1:(CCControlSlider *)sender
 {
// Change volume of your sounds
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:sender.value];

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"boom.mp3"];      
  }
```

The slider appears when i click pause menu, only problem when I click resume it won't go away :(. Any suggestions would be nice. I was thinking about something that when you touch resume you can eliminate or hide the sound sliders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exemplary picking out a part of the code that cried out to me (it sounded like "Hiiilp! Hiiiilp!").

```
_pauseScreen =[[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"pause picture.png"] retain];
```

You retain an autoreleased object, which is also retained by the parent node because you add it as child to self. Now I don't see any `release` anywhere which leads me to believe you're leaking this and other such retained objects.

Recommendation: do not retain objects which you add to the node hierarchy via addChild anyway. It's superfluous. And for the next project, use ARC.

Comment: ok, that is helpful advice. Also, my game works on simulator but is leaking going to effect my game on the actual iPhone. Also any advice how to get rid of sliders after you touch resume?